# Nuget PackageReleaseNotes as link instead of static text

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I can successfully create a nuget package.

I have this:

```xml
<PackageReleaseNotes>See https://github.com/foo/bar/CHANGELOG.md</PackageReleaseNotes>
```

That renders as static text. Can I configure it to render as a link instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, NuGet does not support rich text format in `PackageReleaseNotes` (nor does it support fetching content from link or file) yet. There is an [NuGet issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1203) related to this problem which links to other relevant issues (GUI, etc).

There is a nice little trick which can be used in .csproj file though. For example, if you have a `ReleaseNotes.txt` file:

```
1.0.5 Release (2022-09-20)

 - Changed foo

1.0.4 Release (2022-08-13)

 - Changed bar

1.0.0 Release (2022-01-15)

 - Initial release
```

Then you can use this snippet in your `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReleaseNotes>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/ReleaseNotes.txt"))</PackageReleaseNotes>
```

To inject its contents into the package `.nuspec` on build. Of course, you need to make sure to actually update release notes before hitting Build.